# How can I create shiny inputs with choices from a reactive function in the server

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

This should be a simple problem.  Im trying to create a GUI that will have two input selectors (x-var and y-var) that will be used to create a plot using ggplot.  For some reason shiny doesnt recognize the function in the server intended to extract column names as the options for the input selectors.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("x", "X-Variable", nms()),
    selectInput("y", "Y-Variable", nms()),
    textInput("plottitle", label = NULL),
    actionButton("gobutton", "Create Plot"),
    p("Click here to create your plot")
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("dataplot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  nms <- reactive({
    names(mtcars)
  })

  dplot <- eventReactive(input$gobutton, {
    p_data <- ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) + 
      geom_point()+
      ggtitle(input$plottitle)

    print(p_data)
  })

  output$dataplot <- renderPlot({
    dplot()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `nms()` in the UI, but the UI doesn't know what `nms` is because it's defined in the server. The UI and server do not share variables, they can't see what the other has.  It looks like what you're trying to do should be achieved using `uiOuptut` + `renderUI` instead of the `selectInput` -- read the documentation for `uiOutput` and you'll get your answer